# What considerations must I make to a potentially really busy web service?

Tags: database, wcf, database-design, specifications, high-traffic

As per title, assume I have a WCF web service that, at specific times of the day, will encounter huge amounts of traffic/calls. Each call to the web service will invoke a write to a database and a read from the same database.

Technically, what must I take into consideration (if anything) with regards to protecting the database from any unwanted effects from reading and writing to it very frequently?

Also, must the WCF web service be coded/structured any differently with this in mind?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 basic approaches:

- Throttle the input. Use the throttling function in WCF to reduce the load on your database.
- Put a layer of protection between the WCF calls and your database. For example a queue to protect against incomming messages and a cache to protect against excessive reads.

Which one you choose will depend on your situation. The first one is very cheap to implement since it is just a configuration change, but your users of the WCF service may notice that they are being throttled. The second is better for the users of the service, but much more expensive to implement.

Comment: Thanks so much Shiraz, very helpful response. Based on the fact there will be a queue, I'm assuming there must be a locking mechanism in place to write to this queue? Is that right? Thanks again.